# Running python file within a shell script : module not found error

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, importerror

I'm beginner to both bash and python.

I'm working in Ubuntu env.

to be short, I've created a shell script 'format_data.sh' that runs python file 'proc_ko.py' within it.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
python path/to/python/file/proc_ko.py
...
```

And the python file 'proc_ko.py' imports a module called khaiii

```
from khaiii import KhaiiiApi
api = KhaiiiApi()
...
```

But when I try to execute 'format_data.sh', I get this import error from python file.

**Traceback (most recent call last):

File "media/sf_projet/pe/pe/PROGRAMME/SCRIPTS/proc_ko.py", line 5, in

from khaiii import KhaiiiApi

ImportError: No module named khaiii**

which doesn't occur when I execute python file independently.

Python file 'proc_ko.py' itself doesn't have any error and 'khaiii' is well installed.

so I don't understand why import error occurs only through the shell script.

If u need more details to figure out, I'll be happy to provide. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? `python` points to python 2, `python3` points to python 3

Comment: $python --version    >>python 3.7.3

Comment: Please post the complete path to `khaiii.py` and the value of `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Alright so I tried to find `PYTHONPATH` by `echo $PYTHONPATH` but I had a blank as the answer then I did `which python` and it gave me 'home/tim/anaconda3/bin/python'. The path to `khaiii.py` is 'home/tim/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/khaiii/khaiii.py'

Comment: I just recognized that I have a python installed under `home/tim/anaconda3/bin/python` but also under `usr/bin/python3.xxx` ... Could this be a problem?